# How to execute PowerShell scripts in C# using the Task Parallel Library

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, task-parallel-library

I am currently executing PowerShell scripts as follows:

```
internal void RunScript(PowerShell powerShell, Runspace runspace, Script script, IDictionary parameters = null, Action<ICollection<PSObject>> callback = null)
    {
        SetupScriptRun(powerShell, runspace, script, parameters);

        powerShell.BeginInvoke(new PSDataCollection<PSObject>(), null, psCallback =>
        {
            ICollection<PSObject> results = powerShell.EndInvoke(psCallback);
            LogWarningsAndErrors(powerShell, runspace, script, parameters);
            if (callback != null)
            {
                callback(results);
            }
        }, null);
    }
```

I'd like to wrap this Asynchronous Programming Model (APM) code in a Task as described here:

[TPL and Traditional .NET Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423.aspx)

I've tried to create the task using the following method but I can't work out what the parameters should be:

```
var task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.FromAsync<PSDataCollection<PSObject>>(???);
```

How can I can wrap the BeginInvoke/EndInvoke methods in a task?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using the non-async Powershell Invoke() as follows:

```
internal Task RunScript(PowerShell powerShell, Runspace runspace, Script script, IDictionary parameters = null, Action<ICollection<PSObject>> callback = null, object state = null)
    {
        SetupScriptRun(powerShell, runspace, script, parameters);

        return Task.Factory.StartNew<ICollection<PSObject>>((o) =>
            {
                var results = powerShell.Invoke();
                LogWarningsAndErrors(powerShell, runspace, script, parameters);

                if (callback != null)
                {
                    callback(results);
                }

                return results;
            }, state);
    }
```

Comment: What type is Script ? and SetupScriptRun and LogWarningsAndErrors methods ?